# IPersistenceBookmarks ValidationError When I write to UiPath Queue from Studio

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-api

I am writing my first UiPath Queue producer but when I run my RPA app from within Studio I hit the IPersistenceBookmarks ValidationException.

This is a simple project and I don’t have any bookmarks. Not even sure what a bookmark is. Any idea on how to fix this issue when I try to write to a UiPath queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively common error when people are putting together their first UiPath Orchestrator Queue processing program.

**The UiPath Orchestration Template**

When you work with Queues, you must create your UiPath project using the Orchestration Template, not the [Blank Project](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Make-this-UiPath-Hello-World-example-the-first-project-in-your-RPA-journey) used for so many other RPA scripts. The UiPath Orchestration Template has all of the required facilities built into it for reading UiPath Queues, adding UiPath Queue items and deleting items from the queue as well.

[image]

Use the Orchestrator template and your project will be [published to UiPath](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Assistant-and-publish-to-UiPath-Orchestrator) Orchestrator in no time.